# How do you list all files that have changed in a mercurial repository, limited to only draft changesets?

Tags: mercurial, dvcs, tortoisehg

**Is there a way in mercurial (or TortoiseHg) to do the following?**

1. Get a list of only draft changesets (draft phase, i.e. not pushed and public)
2. Get a list of all files that have been changed in that subset of changesets.
3. As an added bonus, spit those out to an output file (if done via command line)

I figure I could probably look at outgoing changesets and then somehow run through each of those manually, but there must be a way to do this in a single command via the command line.

---

**UPDATE**

One extra requirement I would like is to show how the file has changed. If you go into TortoiseHg and click on the button (in the synchronize toolbar) with the tooltip <kbd>filter outgoing changesets to remote repository</kbd> you get a list of the draft changesets. Clicking on each changeset lists the outgoing files and has a **+** for additions, an **x** for deletions and an absence of either symbol for modifications. I would like to be able to get this information via the command line as well.

**Relevant Version Information:**

`TortoiseHg 2.4.1` (with the following supporting software)
`Mercurial 2.2.2`
`Python 2.6.6`
`Qt 4.7.4`

I should also mention I'm on Windows(7x64) to prevent answers that use *nix command line utilities to pipe commands around. I could always get unxutils or cygwin etc., but I'd rather not at this time (unless no other option exists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two slightly different solutions

### Improved version of Jason, with status indicators

I'm too lazy to fight with excessive newlines in output, `sort -u` will kill it anyway, so

Changed style-file (added status and \n before keywords, because {file_*} keywords output space-separated list, contrary to {file})

```
changeset = '{file_mods}\n{file_dels}\n{file_adds}'
file_mod = '\nM {file_mod}'
file_add = '\nA {file_add}'
file_del = '\nD {file_del}'
```

Used hg log -r "outgoing(PATH)" (may be improved, placed in [revsetalias] probably somehow)

Sample output

```
M 404.php


M functions.php
M readme.txt
M screenshot.png
M style.css


M readme.txt
M sidebar.php
M style.css


M comments.php
M functions.php
M header.php
M readme.txt
M sidebar.php
M style.css


M footer.php
M functions.php
M header.php
M search.php
M style.css


A readme.txt
M functions.php


M functions.php




A 404.php
A archive.php
A archives.php
A comments.php
A footer.php
A functions.php
A header.php
A html5.js
A image.php
A index.php
A license.txt
A links.php
A page.php
A screenshot.png
A search.php
A sidebar.php
A single.php
A style.css
```

## Status-based solution

In case of single range of outgoing (push affect only one branch) фтв availability of possibility to define outgoing first and last changeset (handwork for Windows):
`hg log -r "(min(outgoing()))"` (hereinafter A)
`hg log -r "(max(outgoing()))"` (hereinafter B, probably always tip)

`hg status` with two specified revisions will show all changes with their respective statuses

`hg st --rev A --rev B`

For the same repo from solution 1 and the same range

```
hg st --rev 1 --rev 7
M 404.php
M comments.php
M footer.php
M functions.php
M header.php
M screenshot.png
M search.php
M sidebar.php
M style.css
A readme.txt
```

If working directory parent is latest changeset in outgoing range (tip and WD-parent is tip is casual case) secong revision in `st` can be skipped (by default `hg status` will compare with working dir) and status becomes `hg status --rev A`

Comment: I'll give it a whirl at work tomorrow morning. This looks very promising, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I've found a way to do this, ***except for one more requirement I added to the question*** (see edit in question).

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3041751/9732) stackoverflow answer, I can list all files that have changed in changesets that are outgoing (another way of saying they are in the draft phase):

- Create a file (I called it *c:\temp\out-style.txt*)
- In the file put the following:

> changeset = "{files}" 
>   file = "{file}\n"

- Execute the following command from the command line:

> hg -q outgoing --style C:\temp\out-style.txt | sort -u

I'm using powershell to do this, so I did the following (based on my findings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13032584/9732)) to pipe the output into a file called *c:\temp\outgoing-changes.txt* (addition in **bold**):

> hg -q outgoing --style C:\temp\out-style.txt | sort -u **| Out-File C:\Temp\outgoing-changes.txt -encoding UTF8**

So all that is missing now is *how* each file changed (addition, deletion, modification). This is information I would like to know.